# Overloading operators with multiple member fields

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload different operators, such as `>, +=, -=, >=`, but for some reason I keep getting same error, *expression must be bool type (or be convertable to bool)*

**Example**

```
Money operator>=(const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return lhs.pounds, rhs.pounds >= lhs.pence, rhs.pence;
}
```

****I've also tried****

```
Money operator>=(const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.pounds, rhs.pounds) < (lhs.pence, rhs.pence);
}
```

I'm trying to compare objects that inherit the object that I'm trying to compare, for example.

`accounts[paramB]` is an account object inside `std::vector<Account*>`. The `Accounts` class inherits `Money` class, and has a `Money balance;` member;

```
Account::Money getBalance(); { return 0; }
Savings::Money getBalance { return (balance.pounds, balance.pence) }

Money amount;

if(accounts[paramB]->getBalane() > amount)
    ...
```

Is there a way I can compare the same object without have to specify pounds and pence seperately?

```
if(accounts[paramB]->getBalane().pounds > amount.pounds && accounts[paramB]>getBalance().pence > amount.pence)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return lhs.pounds, rhs.pounds >= lhs.pence, rhs.pence;
```

is parsed as

```
return lhs.pounds, (rhs.pounds >= lhs.pence), rhs.pence;
```

so is equivalent to

```
return rhs.pence;
```

`std::tie` is the way to go (in general case), but you don't use it correctly (and your return type is wrong). It should be

```
bool operator < (const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.pounds, lhs.pence) < (rhs.pounds, rhs.pence);
    // Might be more appropriate in your case
    // return (100 * lhs.pounds + lhs.pence) < (100 * rhs.pounds + rhs.pence);
    // or, with appropriate helper function
    // return to_pence(lhs) < to_pence(rhs);
}

bool operator > (const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return rhs < lhs;
}

bool operator <= (const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return !(rhs < lhs);
}

bool operator >= (const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return rhs <= lhs;
}
```

Comment: Changing return type to bool, and comparing only pence, solved the issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of comparisons must be `bool` and cannot be `Money`. This is a simple logic expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you are doing here:

```
Money operator>=(const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return lhs.pounds, rhs.pounds >= lhs.pence, rhs.pence;
}
```

This expression looks strange to me, and I'm not sure if it is even valid or not. When you overload this kind of comparison operator, it must return either `true` or `false`: a bool type. What if you did something like this?

```
bool operator>=(const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.pounds >= rhs.pounds) && (lhs.pence >= rhs.pence);
}
```

I hope I'm not being presumptuous on what it is you're trying to do. This example uses the "and" binary logic operator and compares the `pounds` field and the `pence` field. You could also use the binary "or".

```
bool operator>=(const Money& lhs, const Money& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.pounds >= rhs.pounds) || (lhs.pence >= rhs.pence);
}
```

Either way, this type of operator should return `bool` and not `Money`.

Comment: Those `operator >=` break strict [weak-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) though.